# Why are these faces acting like an n-gon?

Tags: modeling

It should select these faces one by one, since they are quads as you can see from cuts, but its like, selecting a n-gon. Why?

[image: Picture]

Comment: It looks like you may have an additional mesh (The one you have selected). Try deleting it.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that was the case. For those that has the same problem and wonder why did it happen, dont connect edges with "F". Use the knife tool.

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy Blendering!

Comment: @Ceroder Use J instead of F. No need for knife tool. Also if you have an answer of your own please post it so this question can be finialized.